# Detect blocked pop-up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

Ok so I am using Chromium for Ubuntu 9.10 and cannot get this working using the normal means of detecting a pop-up blocker which are...

```
var popup = window.open(...);
var blocked;
if(!popup) {
    blocked = true;
} else {
    blocked = false;
}
```

Also, the accepted solution in this SO post, [Detect blocked popup in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome), does not work.

Comment: It seems that window.open() in Chrome is returning a defined object even when the popup is blocked

Answer (score 2):

popup.innerHeight no longer works.  Use outerHeight, if greater than zero then it was not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a page on the same domain, check `popup.innerHeight`. If it's 0, the popup was most likely blocked.

Comment: console.log(popup.outerHeight) reveals 275, which is actually the height attribute I am passing to window.open

Comment: Flash84x: You might want to try `innerHeight` too.

Comment: innerHeight is 0 when the popup is blocked and when the popup is visible, so no dice :-\

Comment: Also when it's visible? I find that hard to believe and I am unable to reproduce it being zero when a previously-blocked (and then manually allowed) popup is visible.