# Determine if user has pop-up blocker on Flex

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, apache-flex, popup

My application pops up help windows outside of Flex on several occasions.  I need to warn the user to allow pop ups from my app if they have the pop-up blocker on.

Does anyone know how to determine this from inside of Flex and then how to have the browser pop up the "allow pop ups from this site" thing after that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use Flex's External interface in conjunction with one of the JavaScript answers.

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface

Answer (score 1):

I would use javascript to check for popup blockers and pass the result to Flex. Here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome) that may help.

Comment: Is there a way to call javascript from inside flex and then back?

Answer (score -1):

To tell you the truth, I am not a Flex expert, by any means, but if you are not using Flex's built-in dialog tools, I would recommend using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com). You can do anything from simple alerts, to complex HTML forms, and even externally loaded pages, if you want.

The jQueryUI has their own built-in [dialog tools](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), which does not trip the browser's pop-up blocker.

Comment: This is 100% not an option.  This is a flex project, not an html/js project.