# Legally avoiding popup blocking

Tags: javascript

What is causing some browsers to see my code as unsolicited?

I have a web site devoted to helping people with interactive sessions. It starts with the user clicking [Begin] so this is a consented action. This should (1) open a popup while (2) redirecting the first page to a end page as below :

```
<head>  
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
      function openwindow(){window.open("{INTERACTION}","interaction","resizable=0,width=800,height=600,status=0");}</SCRIPT>
</head>   
<body>
<FORM action="end.php" method="{METHOD}" >  
<input type="submit"  class="button" 
       onClick="javascript: openwindow()" 
       value="Begin" />
</FORM>
</body>
```

As said, this is not trying to open an unrequested popup but some strains of IE and Chrome appear to be treating it as such. I have been trying to get a fix, most recently digesting [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome).

In it Bobince comments

> these days, you don't really need to ask the question “was my unsolicited popup blocked?”, because the answer is invariably “yes” — all the major browsers have the popup blocker turned on by default. Best approach is only ever to window.open() in response to a direct click, which is almost always allowed.I'm quite happy to buy into this principle because I simply want my popup to open.

What is causing some browsers to see my code as unsolicited?

I'd appreciate any help you could give me. (as you might have guessed, client side is not my bag and this topic has been bugging me for ages).

Many thanks in advance (and fingers crossed)
Giles

Comment: For what it's worth your example works for me in all major browsers. Where is it not working for you? You may still have problems with more draconian third-party popup or script blockers, but then that's always the case. Best provide a normal link to your main interaction page so it can still be used without pop-ups. (Personally I will always use that anyway as I'm one of the many users that utterly despise them.)

Comment: Wow! thanks for testing. I've been getting reports that ie9 on win7  blocks with only a momentary warning message that's easy for most to oversee

Comment: Working for me in IE9/Win7 FWIW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No much you can do. You could ask your users to disable pop-up blockers or inform them that a pop-up blocker is enabled by checking the window object ref returned by window.open()

e.g.

```
var w = window.open('http://domain.com');
if(!w) { 
   //an alert in this example
   alert('oops..seems like a pop-up blocker is enabled. Please disable');
}
```

you could find another way and try what Brad suggests.

Comment: Interesting ... would this work for all instances of blocking ??? ... (if so, I could build a if - else statement to either open popup or return an alert?)

Comment: if a pop up is blocked you should not get a ref to the new window. I am not 100% certain but you can try the code. You could display an alert or use what Brad suggests in his answer

Comment: Checking `!w` isn't quite sufficient. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089792/103842

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything you can do about this.  Some popup blockers still block everything, even in response to a user clicking.  The best you can do is suggest your users turn off popup blockers, or find a different way to do what you want to do.  A popular method is the div that appears on top of all others on your page, like [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/).

There are [many jQuery plugins](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/top-10-jquery-modal-box-plugins/) which make this easy.

Comment: OK I see your point but is this solution safe? A lot of our users are still circa IE6

Comment: @giles, jQuery generally works fine with IE6, and I'd imagine most of the plugins do too.  Test it, and if it doesn't work, try a different plugin or alter your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least?) 2 options to deal with this:

- if you want to keep using popups, display a very visible warning for your users, pointing them to instructions on how to configure their browser to whitelist your domain (like the banners that appear on top of StackOverlow.com when you gain new privileges, or even like the banners Chrome is showing for actions - they are web-based as well);
- use an iFrame and load its content based on your user's click.