# popup don't blocked any more

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to work with jquery to make popup

but my problem it's bloked from google

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = true;
    if (event.target == this & flag) {
        window.open('<? echo $lllllink ; ?>');
        flag = false;
    }
});
</script>
```

i think do it with any open to do mouse left click automatic but it's not work too
any one can help ?

Comment: Browsers routinely block pop-ups unless they're tied to a user event like a mouse-click. Unless the user consciously allows pop-ups this won't work. It won't work if you try to simulate a mouse-click either.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192889/legally-avoiding-popup-blocking

Answer (score 3):

Most modern browsers block pop-ups by default.

However, if you are using jQuery. I recommend looking at the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). This is part of the HTML page and does not get blocked by the browser. This is in general the more elegant and preferred way of doing pop-ups these days.