# Pop up enabling

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web app in ASP.NET, when you  a click a link, am opening a pop up window in a new page, while i do that, if pop ups are disabled in end user computer, is there a way to detect that & enable pop up blockers? so that the new window can automatically open.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot enable popups if they are blocked. It's a little different as to how to tell if your popup was blocked. See this answer [Detect blocked popup in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome/1089792#1089792)

The best thing to do is to detect if the popup was blocked and ask the used to allow popups for your site.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't control a person's browser settings from your website. That would be a big security problem and no body would have bothered implementing a pop-up blocker in the first place.

**UPDATE:** 
See Bala's comment. One thing is detecting that it was blocked and another thing is changing the user's browser behavior.