# How do I detect whether popups are blocked in chrome

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm trying to to load facebook auth page for users to connect their fb accounts with my site. The problem is it's a different domain. Code is as below

```
var left = (screen.width/2)-(550/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(250/2);
    fbPopUp = window.open(authorizeURL,'fbWindow','menubar=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,width=400,height=275, top='+top+' , left='+left);
```

How do I find out whether this window actually opened or not?
I tried solution of [Detect blocked popup in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect blocked popup in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically there's a bug in Chrome. Although it hides the popup, it still executes and you still get the window object back - so regular checks don't work.

Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
var popup = window.open(url);

if (popup) {
  popup.onload = function () {
    console.log(popup.innerHeight > 0 ? 'open' : 'blocked');
  }
} else {
  console.log('blocked');
}
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/uticev/3/

Comment: This has apparently broken in newer versions of Chome. Doesn't work for me in "19.0.1084.52 m" at least

Answer (score 5):

I was searching and searching, and finally found this, so I had to share, becuase like other people said it is broken in newer versions of chrome. So the fixed solution is this:

```
var popUp = window.open( url );
setTimeout( function() {
   if ( popUp.outerHeight === 0 ) {   
      alert('blocked'); 
   }
}, 25);
```

Comment: for me the popUp.outerHeight is 'undefined'

Comment: Yes, `popUp.outerHeight` is `null` because when a popup is blocked, `window.open` returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

just modified Remy answer. This works for me.

```
        var win = window.open("", 'child','width=10,height=10,status=no,resizable=no');
        var objwin = new RegExp('object','gi');
        var isblock = false;

        if(objwin.test(String(win))) {
            if(typeof win.outerHeight ==="undefined" || parseInt(win.outerHeight)<10){
                isblock = true;
            }
            win.close();
        }else{
               isblock = true;
        }

        if(isblock){
          // do something here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var popup = window.open(host);
popup.onload = function (){
    if (!popup.innerHeight > 0){
        popup.close();
        // Popup blocked
    } else {
        // Popup enabled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well for me:

```
loginWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', options);

setTimeout(function () {
    if (!loginWindow || loginWindow.closed || typeof loginWindow.closed == 'undefined' || parseInt(loginWindow.outerWidth) == 0) {
        alert('Turn off pop-up blocker and try again.');
    }
    else {
        loginWindow.focus();
    }
}, 500);
```