# Fallback if window.open() is blocked by popup blockers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I want to default to `target=_blank` if `window.open()` fails.

Eg. The user clicks a link that invokes `window.open()`. However, the popup is blocked by a popup blocker. In this scenario, I want a new window to open instead. Is this possible?

P.S. I have jQuery loaded.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome  Or this: http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com/2010/11/window-open-popup-blocker-detect-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Assuming that this is your A tag

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="myLink" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

Then using jquery, add a click event handler to this:

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e){
    if(!window.open("http://www.w3schools.com")){
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

Comment: This won't work on Chrome.  Chrome returns a valid `Window` object from `window.open` even if the popup is blocked.