# How to check Popup blocker enabled Without loading popup window in chrome using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used following code in firefox,its working.But not working in chrome.

```
var myTest = window.open("about:blank","","directories=no,height=100,width=100,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,titlebar=no,top=0,location=no");
  if (!myTest) {
    alert("A popup blocker was detected.");
  } else {
    myTest.close();
    alert("No popup blocker was detected.");
  }
```

How to check Popup blocker enabled in chrome using Jquery.**I checked  [Earlier discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome) in Jsfiddle.net.But its not working in chrome.Please help me,give answer with jsfiddle.net.**

Comment: Why 'using jQuery'? I'm not aware of any jQuery specific methods/tools/API to help with this particular task. Nor am I certain that it would work in Chrome, given that the above method (which is the only one I could think of) failed.