# how to throw an alert saying " please turn off the pop up blocker"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect if a browser is blocking a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup)

hi iam trying to open a child window with disabled toolbar.......

how to check whether the child window is opened or not and then display this alert??

can someone help with code.........

Comment: Why not put your information on the page being viewed, where it belongs?

Comment: @Carl: look at the history; OP has ignored this advice several times and seems dead set on implementing the ghastly user-hostile solution that everyone hates. It even appears to be for a login form, which makes the idea of opening with disabled browser chrome even more hilariously inappropriate.

Comment: @bobince: Yep, agree completely. I tend to react with hostility to SEO questions ("how can I game the system without getting caught?"), and this is an even more obscene violation of users' wishes. I hope this guy's company goes belly up.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a new window using `window.open()`, it returns a handle to the (theoretically) opened window.  You can then test that handle to determine whether the window is open:

```
var child = window.open("mypopup.html");

// some popup blockers prevent the window from being created (!child) and
// others just close them before they're displayed (child.closed)

if (!child || child.closed) {
    // tell the user to turn off their popup blocker
}
```

Popups are very intrusive, however, and you should consider trying to display the "popup" information within the page.  In particular, have a look at "dialog" scripts.  If you're using jQuery, a very nice [Dialog widget](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) is included in the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if popups are blocked, `window.open()` will return a `null`, not a window object. You can read it in an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537632(v=VS.85).aspx):

> If you are not sure whether a pop-up
>   window is blocked, check your
>   functions that return a window object.
>   You can tell if a pop-up window has
>   been blocked if these functions return
>   null. In particular, you need to check
>   the value of window.open to avoid
>   script errors when your pop-up windows
>   are blocked.

Also, this will give you some hints about detection of popup blockers: http://www.visitor-stats.com/articles/detect-popup-blocker.php

Answer (score -1):

You need to give us the Javascript you are using so that we can help. You will need an 'if' statement.

Display alerts like this in javascript:

alert('Please turn off your pop-up blocker');