# How do I detect that my pop-up window failed (due to a pop-up blocker)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I detect if a browser is blocking a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup)

I want to open a new window (onclick) to a page on Facebook (facebook.com/sharer.php).

However, if this fails due to pop up blockage, I want to detect it and change it to a link instead (new tab).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(!window.open()){
//pop up failed.
}
```

Comment: After that, how do I open a new link to another page?

Comment: "open a new link to another page" > if you meant Pop-up, then inside the if block try another window.open, else u can use document.location = "http://New Location";

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#anchor').click(function(){

   if(!window.open()){
      //pop up failed.


     window.open('http://www.example.net/'); // open url in new tab
     window.location = "http://www.example.net/" // open in current window

   }

});
```