# Open url in same tab if window.open not working in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ecmascript-6, safari

Is there a way to know if window.open failed to open url in new tab in IOS if user has enabled pop up blocker as **on** in phone settings ?

If the url did not get opened in new tab, I want to use window.location.href and open in same tab.I need that identifier which tells me window.open failed.Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is propablly a duplicate of [How do I detect that my pop-up window failed (due to a pop-up blocker)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559749/how-do-i-detect-that-my-pop-up-window-failed-due-to-a-pop-up-blocker)

Code for what you're trying to do would be this:

```
var some_url = "some_url"
if(!window.open(some_url)) {
      window.location.href = some_url
}
```

Does this aswear your question? - I'm sorry, I cannot write comments because of my low reputation.