# javascript window.location in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am diverting user to some url through `window.location` but this url opens in the same tab in browser. I want it to be open in new tab. Can I do so with window.location? Is there another way to do this action?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs

Comment: Is `window.location` a requirement? Or can other JS solutions be offered ?

Comment: @Khez: other JS can be offered.

Comment: you can use the window.open()

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this, unless you're writing a browser extension. You could try using `window.open` and hoping that the user has their browser set to open new windows in new tabs.

Comment: No need to hope, just pass **_blank** as the second parameter :) `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Answer (score 586):

```
window.open('https://support.wwf.org.uk', '_blank');
```

The second parameter is what makes it open in a new window. Don't forget to read [Jakob Nielsen's informative article](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html) :)

Comment: but what if your browsers has blocked settings on popup? this will not wok.

Comment: @Alex meh...not really the "right" answer. Trying this in Firefox, where I prevent pop-up windows, this code fails.

Answer (score 61):

You can even use

```
window.open('https://support.wwf.org.uk', "_blank") || window.location.replace('https://support.wwf.org.uk');
```

This will open it on the same tab if the pop-up is blocked.

Comment: I would avoid this solution because window.open in some cases could return null (but still open a new window as expected) while also triggering location.replace on the current tab resulting in two open tabs with the new url. Using a try/catch described in this answer may be a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/27725432/811533.

Answer (score 22):

This works for me on Chrome 53. Haven't tested anywhere else:

```
function navigate(href, newTab) {
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = href;
   if (newTab) {
      a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
   }
   a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

with jQuery its even easier and works on Chrome as well

```
$('#your-button').on('click', function(){
       $('<a href="https://www.some-page.com" target="blank"></a>')[0].click();    
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Rather going for pop up,I personally liked this solution, mentioned on this Question thread
[JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab/5141926)

```
$(document).on('click','span.external-link',function(){
        var t               = $(this), 
            URL             = t.attr('data-href');        
        $('<a href="'+ URL +'" target="_blank">External Link</a>')[0].click();

    });
```

Working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgga124n/).

Answer (score 0):

We have to dynamically set the attribute target="_blank" and it will open it in new tab.
`document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute('target', '_blank')`

`document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click()`

If you want to open in new window, get the href link and use window.open

`var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");`

`window.open(url, "","height=500,width=500");`

Don't provide the second parameter as _blank in the above.