# open new tab(window) by clicking a link in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that displays rows with `go` and `delete` buttons.

If a user clicks `go`, it should open new tab/window with url built from the row's data.

how can I do this in jquery? What I'm doing is :

```
$('.go').click( function () {
   var wid = {{ wid|tojson|safe }};
   var sid = $(this).prop('id');
   url = $script_root + '/' + wid + '/' + sid;

   // go to url
});
```

some update:

What I'm really tring to accomplish is dynamically update `href` of an `<a>` element.

```
<a id="foo" href="#">foo</a>
<script type="text/javascript>
$('#foo').click( function() {
  $(this).prop('href', 'http://www.google.com/');
});
</script>
```

which doesn't work (fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/6eLjA/)

Comment: isn't it jQuery code.?

Comment: you can provide "_blank" while calling window.open

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554108/javascript-window-location-in-new-tab

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

This will open in new tab (if your code is synchronous and in this case it is. in other case it would open a window)

Comment: What do you mean by *if your code is synchronous*?

Comment: @VisioN This code will not open new tab: $.get('someurl', function(){ window.open('anotherurl', '_blank'); }), it will open a window because ajax request is asynchronous by default (you can change it)

Comment: I'm getting an alert in google chrome telling that is has blocked a "Pop up". Any help with this ? Is there any way to by pass it ?

Comment: Tareck - window.open should be placed inside of a click event to prevent google chrome from blocking the pop up.

Comment: Not too important, but could you surround 'url' in quotes? If you entered the URL parameter without quotes, it wouldn't run.