# How to open link in new window with "window.location()"?

Tags: javascript

I use this script to **find link around and open it on click**. But it always open it in same tab. How can I adjust it to open **found link** in new tab/window?

```
<script>
    
    (function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-clickable-blank').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); 
    return false;
    });
    });
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript window.location in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554108/javascript-window-location-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `window.open()` instead of `window.location()`

```
window.open(
  $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Comment: This is not working. It just do nothing on click. Maybe because new popups are blocked in modern browsers?

Comment: @Michal yes it maybe get blocked but there is a workaround explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628949/window-open-popup-getting-blocked-during-click-event

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host;
url = url + '/print.php;   
var print_window = window.open(url, 'Print', 'height=600,width=900');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open():`

```
 window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', 'name');
```

Function description:

**name** is a name of the window. Following names are supported:

- **_blank** - URL is loaded into a new tab. This is default.
- **_parent** - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- **_self** - URL replaces the current page
- **_top** - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded

Comment: This is not working. It just do nothing on click. Maybe because new popups are blocked in modern browsers?