# Javascript password + button open URL in targeted element

Tags: javascript, button, passwords, target

I learned how to open a link using a password and button.
I used the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit" onClick="window.location=url;" />

<script>
$("#btn").click(function() {
window.location="example.com/"+$("#text").val();})
</script>
```

What I would like to figure out is whether I can target a div element for the link to open within.

I've been using the following script to load html pages into a specified div element with a link:

```
<div class="item1" id="pageone"></div>
<a href="" onclick="loadSAMEDiv1(); return false;">link</a>

<script>
function loadSAMEDiv1() { 
$.ajax({ 
 url: 'item1.html', 
 success: function(data) { 
      $('#pageone').html(data); 
 } 
 }); 
} 
</script>
```

I guess I'm wondering if there's a way to make the password url made by the first script open in a targeted div, like it does in the second script. So when you click the button element it will make the url using the password entered into the text box and load it into a div like #pageone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with Ajax `load()`. Try this.

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Submit"/>

<div class="item1" id="pageone"></div>

<script>
    $("#btn").on("click", function() {
        $("#pageone").load("example.com/"+$("#text").val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked extremely well, thanks!

Comment: Do you know a way to make the page open in a new window or tab? The window.location script I originally used will open a link in the same tab.

Comment: If you are using ajax to load a `div` that will only work in the current tab. If you just need `window.location` to open in new tab, try `window.open`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13682407/14199515) article.

Comment: Also if that answered your question, please accept and upvote.

Comment: Thanks - I'm new so I can't upvote but I've accepted :)