# jquery dialog for opening a popu up window in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plain javascript function for opening a pop up window. This works fine in chrome and firefox. But in Safari, since pop up blocker is enabled by default, its neither opening the page nor there is no error notice.(is it possible to get an error notice?)
Can this be done using any jquery method without using `window.open()`.
Please someone help me in this?

```
var gomWin = window.open(popupURL, 'params');
```

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup, it gives examples on how to detect if popups are blocked in Javascript.

Comment: @jaco - Thanks for the reply. This solution doesn't seem to work in safari. Its not alerting anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is no jQuery method that I know of to do that.

In order to test whether the call to `window.open` succeeded your should test the returned value:

```
var gomWin = window.open(popupURL, 'params');
if (gomWin === null)
  alert("Popup blocked!");
```

Comment: Thansk for the reply. if (gomWin === null) did not give any alert. But         if (typeof gomWin == 'undefined'){alert("Popup blocked!");} gave the alert. But the problem is it alerts even if the pop up is not blocked. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: It might be a behavior related to Safari. You may want to test the returned value is several different ways as shown in the post suggested by Jaco.