# Open window and close immediately

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, window

There is a way in JS to open window and close it **immediately**, that it **will not open in new tab** , I just want want to open a window (like in background if possible ) do some check on it and immediately close it, **without the effect that the new tab is open** , is it possible?

Something like this but without the effect that the window is opened...

```
 var popup = window.open("http://www.google.com");

popup.close();
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is solution which I found but it's flicking sometimes and I  want to avoid it...

```
function goNewWin() {

    var TheNewWin = window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", 'TheNewpop', 'toolbar=1,location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');

    TheNewWin.blur();
    TheNewWin.close();

}
```

Comment: use an iframe instead

Comment: @JaromandaX - I need the window since I need to check for pop-up blocker if is enabled ...,is it possible with iframe?

Comment: oh, so you want to open a popup, - the "new tab" thing in your question was confusing ... add some [position and size features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features) to the `window.open` to get a popup

Comment: @JaromandaX - not sure that I got it size and position to open and close like background mode ?, can you please provide full example ? Thank you!

Comment: see [this tutorial](http://accessify.com/features/tutorials/the-perfect-popup/)

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks but this not helps for the issue of open and close window like in bg mode..., any other idea?

Comment: @RaynD so what you need is only to check if the popUp blocker is enabled? If yes, you can try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup) or look after others in stackoverflow

Comment: For security reasons, the popup window created by `window.open` must have a minimum size and must be entirely visible on the screen (except if actually moved by the user). Therefore, you will at least see a small window appear briefly before it closes. Documentation: for [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531202(v=VS.85).aspx), for [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: But why you need a 'window' for that, you could make use of  any of ajax methods. Pop up window opening and closing always will flick.. and if the user is using any popup blocker, it will not work.

Comment: What do you need the popup to do? Can you use a hidden iframe (another windowed element)

Answer (score 3):

Even if you call `close` immediately after `window.open`, and even if you try to locate the popup window outside of the screen or to make its size null, you will see it quickly flash on the screen:

```
var popup = window.open("", "Popup", "left=10000,top=10000,width=0,height=0");
popup.close();
```

For security reasons, `window.open` cannot position the popup window outside of the screen and cannot make it smaller than some minimal size. Here is an excerpt of the `window.open` topic in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

> Requested position and requested dimension values in the features list
>   will not be honored and will be corrected if any of such requested
>   value does not allow the entire browser window to be rendered within
>   the work area for applications of the user's operating system. No part
>   of the new window can be initially positioned offscreen. This is by
>   default in all Mozilla-based browser releases.

Similar restrictions apply in Internet Explorer, as indicated in [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531202(v=VS.85).aspx). The minimum size is 250 × 150 in [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx), and the minimum "inner" size is 100 × 100 in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features).

If you absolutely want to avoid the flashing popup window, you can use one of these methods:

- Instead of testing with a call to `window.open`, display a warning on the page to inform the user that the popup blocker option should not be activated (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35663167/1009922) by UncaAlby)
- Let the application run and warn the user, after the fact, if the real popup window could not be displayed
- Use an alternative to `window.open`, for example the [dialog widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) from jQuery UI or the [modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) from Bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

A solution to your problem is by using the `window.postMessage()` function. The `child` is used to notify the `parent` that the window has been loaded and it also works on `cross domain`.

**Child**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    this.opener.postMessage({'loaded': true}, "*");
    this.close();
});
```

**Parent**

```
$(window).on('message', function(event) {     
    alert(event.originalEvent.data.loaded);
});
```

There is also one more method as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668286/detect-blocked-popup-in-chrome/1089792#1089792) of the stackoverflow.

*Full attribution is given to the author of the stack overflow of this thread*

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type= "text/javascript">




function closeWin() {
    window.close();
    return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="return closeWin();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> // Code for page from where you want to open the popup it will open small popup in right bottom corner.

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", "Popup", "height=1, width=1, status=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, top = 100000, left=100000 ");
```

> // In your popup.html add follwing code

```
this.close();
```

Comment: I try it out and its still flicking , any idea how to avoid it that user will not see this effect ?Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about dynamicaly create an iframe on the current window.
Then you can open any page on it, later you could destroy iframe element at any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
```

here you go the answer that it will open the page new tab on button click

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want user to know that you did some process on some url use AJAX call and process

or you do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var popup = window.open("http://www.exampleurl.com/popup.html", "Popup", "height=10, width=10, status=no, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, top = 1, left=1");
</script>
```

here in popup.html you can write code to close it.

Answer (score 0):

This open  window in a hidden mode. not visible to user.
Hope this helps you

```
window.open(path.html,'_blank','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars
=no,resizable=no,left=10000,     top=10000, width=10,    height=10,visible=none', '');
```

Comment: Thanks but it still flicking , any idea how to avoid this flicking issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can avoid the flicker of opening a new window completely. You could check for a pop-up and save the state in a cookie. Then wrap your pop-up checker in a simple if statement with the value of that cookie as the logic. This would avoid the pop-up checker going every single page load.

```
 var popUpCookie = "getCookie";
 if(!popUpCookie){
      var newWin = window.open("http://www.example.com");             

      if(!newWin || newWin.closed || typeof newWin.closed=='undefined') 
      { 
          //POPUP BLOCKED - Create Cookie
      }else{
          //POPUP NOT BLOCKED - Create Cookie
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code i have checked and its working

```
var popup =  window.open("test.php","event","width=900,height=900,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes");
popup.blur();
window.focus();
```

This will open the page but you can't see the page open.