# If popup are blocked in browser then do not show video in window.open() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show message if popup are blocked in the browser and dont want to open video.
I am showing video in window.open() and if popup are blocked in browser then i want to show message that "popup are blocked, please enable them to see video"
Below is my code in react which is not working , it is still showing video when popup are blocked in browser.

```
   openRaceReplay(e = { stopPropagation() { } }, data){
    e.preventDefault();
    let popupOptions = createIframeUrl();
    this.setState(
        {
          replayError: ""
        },
        () => {
            if(data.flashReplayUrl){
                if (isAndroid() || isIos()) {
                    window.open(data.flashReplayUrl, TARGET_WINDOW.SELF);
                } else {
                    const windowHandle = window.open(data.flashReplayUrl,TARGET_WINDOW.BLANK,popupOptions);
         //It is still opening video
                    if(!windowHandle || windowHandle.closed || typeof windowHandle.closed == 'undefined') {
                        this.setState({
                            replayError: MESSAGES.ENABLE_POPUP_MESSAGE
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                this.setState({
                    replayError: MESSAGES.RACE_RACEREPLAY_NOT_AVAILABLE
                  });
            }
        }
      );

}
```

Comment: have you tried using ```debugger;``` to see step through your Web Browser's dev console and check the conditional `if(data.flashReplayUrl)` scope

Comment: Hey , I have tried adding debugger. but it did not helped me

Comment: what web browser are you using?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup

Comment: I am using chrome , and tried in firefox too.

Comment: @xadhix No this is not helping  , i tried it too. :(