# Get reference to a tab opened by click event on <a>

Tags: javascript, tabs

Can we get a reference to a tab which was opened by setting `target` attribute of anchor element to `_blank`.

I basically create a new hidden link and append it to a DOM and then I programmatically simulate click event on that element, is there a way to get a reference to a newly opened tab like we can with `window.open` by doing:

`var newTab = window.open('http://www.google.com/');`

EDIT: Before marking question as duplicate note that I'm unable to use `window.open` at all, hence this question.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I've edited my question.

Comment: Once the window is open, are you looking to immediately do something? Or are you just opening a window with links in it that are not reacting to the script since it was opened after page load?

Comment: @weekapaug I'm talking about tabs, not windows.

Comment: pls explain  "I'm unable to use `window.open` at all"?. Also, can you update question with your code snippet?

Comment: @prsvr - What are you intending to do with the reference to the new tab? That'll guide an answer to your question :)

Comment: @AndrewsGyamfi I simply need to check if the reference is null, so I can determine whether user's browser has pop up blocker on or off.

Comment: Will you have control of the page that is opened in the newly opened tab? i.e. Is it a page you have written or is it an external link?

Comment: This is probably a repeat of the question
[How can I detect if a browser is blocking a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use code directly inside the anchor, you could try to get the reference afterwards (doesn't work in IE).
However you need to set a different target than `_blank`, it will still open a new tab though.

1) Define a target name for your anchor

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="myTarget">Click me</a>
```

2) Get the reference with this "hack":

```
var ref = window.open('', 'myTarget');
```

For more information, see https://medium.com/@bluepnume/every-known-way-to-get-references-to-windows-in-javascript-223778bede2d

Comment: That's what I was looking for, even though I did mention we I can't use window.open() so basically it's a loop, but nevertheless this does answer my original question on how to get a reference to a tab opened by <a> element.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few **red flags** worth considering for the functionality you seek to build before you proceed:

1. You do not have much control (as a developer) to force new links to be opened in browser tabs. That's based on the user's preference as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)
2. `window.open` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) indicates it returns a `null` value *"If the window couldn't be opened"*. You can use this to ***loosely*** check whether a new window was opened or not. However, this might not be consistent across the different browsers.

I will suggest you look at other options (if any) before going down this path.

All the best :)

Comment: #1 is not a problem, #2 actually is, as you can read in my question, I'm not allowed to use it.