# window.open() returning null every time from Firefox responsive view

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was trying to open a new window from the firefox responsive view and write html to its dom, for that I called

```
var wind = window.open('','')
wind.document.write="<h1>Test</h1>"
```

But `window.open()` always returns a null object from the responsive view. It's working well in chrome responsive view though. I've gone through many docs and according to the official docs a null return means the window failed to open, but here it's opening window and returning reference `null`.

Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: The answer appears to be to utilize the specification syntax as here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Did you test this without using empty strings and instead just an empty method call? i.e. your `window.open();`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Comment: I suspect you have pop-ups silently blocked in Firefox - check browser settings as it may appear to do the window creation but then return the null if that occurs.

Comment: This may be helpful for you also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I believe he is saying that it returns null *even though it successfully opens a new window*. I'm experiencing the same bug in the firefox iOS simulator.

Comment: @lnhubbell does giving it an actual name work? `let mywindow = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com',"myname")`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, nope even with a name it successfully open the new window but returns null. It only happens on the firefox iOS simulator, using xCodes iOS simulator works as expected.

Comment: @lnhubbell so a bug there it seems