# Popup blocker handling when app calls displayReplyAllForm method

Tags: office-store

Would you please help me to resolve "Blocked Pop-up Window" problem ?

When I submit our app to AppSource, we get following failure message from partner center.

> Customer Control 1100.5.4.2  Blocked Pop-Up Window
> Pop-up windows triggered by user interaction must not be blocked by browser pop-up blockers on their default settings. A pop-up blocked appears in the browsers when we click on the "insert" button  within your add-in. Please update the offer to correct pop-up window behavior and re-submit your offer.

This is happened when our app calls `displayReplyAllForm` by user interaction. How can I resolve this problem technically ?

Because of following investigation, IMO, Office team should handle this problem.

1. In general, [I should call `window.open` directly from user-interaction for avoiding popup blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587692/2696842).
2. For detecting and handle popup blocker, [I can utilize returned value from `window.open`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917/2696842).

But, I can't do this because `window.open` or something popup logic is wrapped in `displayReplyAllForm`. So, I think it should be handled by Office team.

My suggestion is that Office team provide [promptBeforeOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.dialogoptions?view=word-js-preview#promptbeforeopen) option for `displayReplyAllForm`. I can avoid popup blocker with `promptBeforeOpen` when I use Dialog API, and want to use it in other functions provided by Office.js.

Comment: I submit bug in the GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1377

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft product team has repro the issue and has added this to their backlog. Let's wait they'll fix the problem and we can avoid bad UX in the future.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1377#issuecomment-690049886